# Save As dialog in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web, save-as

Is it possible to display a Save as dialog in angular or through vanilla js?
similar to this? Where a user can specify where to save a file to?

[image: Save As Dialog]

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: Do you mean download of client side generated content or for a download from the server?

Comment: @Diza Is there any updates for tihs question ?